# How do I get the url of a photo after I post it on Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, url, facebook-graph-api

I need to get url of uploaded photo. I posted it and got post's id:

```
JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject()
  .getInnerJSONObject();
String postId = null;

try {
  postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
} 
catch (JSONException e) {
  Log.i("Facebook Error", "JSON error " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Now I'd like to get url of this photo.
How can I get this url?

Comment: when you say you "posted it", what exactly do you mean? How did you post it?

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

Comment: @Dr.Dredel I posted it using "me/photos"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem.

1.Neccessary permissions: publish_actions, user_photos, read_stream

2.Get post_id after photo's upload:

```
postId = graphResponse.getString("post_id");
```

3.Get posts:

```
Request mRequest = new Request(session, "me/feed", null,
                HttpMethod.GET, callback);
```

Find post by id. And get photo's url:

```
String id = json_obj.getString("id");

if (id.equals(postId)) {

String url = json_obj.getString("picture");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to @Tomislav's link, using:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/10150146071831729?access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAC041bexTcyhRKuLWt7MaXNTy3YydqD3mN6lvrmeZCbxiUQGcgBJ7v3rOrvrlzBuByzGjWZBLOhcafA0IuMXjN9tLlaQZDZD`
```

where <10150146071831729> is the ID of the photo you are interested in will return the URL in `link` in the returned JSON object

Reference: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/